# How to find signatures in a non-COM dll for #import into c++

Tags: c++, dll, import, typelib

I have a 3rd party dll that appears to be native C ( Dumpbin shows all C functions). I don't have a lib or .h files. However when I reference this dll in a C# program it magically knows the signatures ( types and descriptions  for all of the paramters ). I need to use the DLL from a C++ app  and can use Dumpbin and Lib to create a lib file but I don't know the signatures ( unless I hand copy them from c# ). #import gives error that it cant find the typelib ( tlh ). The inf must be in the dll since c# can figure it out. How can I figure it out for ( unmanaged ) C++?

Thanks

Comment: `unless I hand copy them from c#` -- And you can't do that because... ?

Comment: If C# allows you to add references to it then it must be managed assembly - otherwise you would have to use p/Invoke.  It must be using C++/CLI if it is managed and has native exports - but those native exports won't necessarily match what appears in C# and will have different types (managed vs/un-managed) so you can't just directly hand copy them from C#.

Comment: Hand copies: There are a lot of signatures and I want to automate it so that I can use update dll's without having to recopy by hand every time. If not automated I'll crash at runtime when signatures don't match. If automated I'll get errors at compile time - much preferred

Comment: @shf301 I'm seeing signature information in the C# Object browser. Does this mean its managed code ?( I'm a C++ guy not to familiar with .net ). The dll is part of a library for talking to a USB device ( has WinUSb dependency ).

Comment: @HappyCoder - yes if it's in the C# object browser that means it's managed code.